# Infinite redirect loop on Android when redirecting from server with AngularJS

Tags: android, node.js, angularjs

I'm building a web/phonegap application for an older version of Android (2.3.x). Everything works great up until I try to add any server redirection into the mix. Here's the scenario:

The server (node.js) has a route listening at '/'. When this route is hit, it checks to see if the there is a session or not. If there is no session, it redirects to /login. Fine, this part works (server wise, anyways).

The problem arises when the client gets the redirect. Because Android 2.3 doesn't support history.pushState, it falls back to hashbangs. This means AngularJS rewrites the url to /#!/login, which causes a server request to '/', which causes the server to check session and redirect to '/login', which causes AngularJS to rewrite the url to /#!/login.. and so on and so forth.. indefinitely.

Any ideas how I can redirect from the server with AngularJS? Should I not be handling this logic in my route but instead try to implement it on the client? There has to be a way to handle this, I'm sure, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow your description: if the server is issuing a redirect, that should be received by the browser, not AngularJS. But perhaps you're getting that URL from the server via xhr, and assigning to $location, which won't work: From the angular docs: "The $location service allows you to change only the URL; it does not allow you to reload the page. When you need to change the URL and reload the page or navigate to a different page, please use a lower level API, $window.location.href." Alternatively, perhaps you need to redirect to `/login#!/login`?

Comment: I wish I could show exactly what's going on, but Angular is "hijacking" my server redirect. Server redirects to /login and angular rewrites this as /#!/login, which causes the server to say "You're not logged in, so redirect to login". The server gets the route as / (which is should, because that's what Angular rewrites it as).

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple object for commanding redirects:
If the user is not logged in, return `{action: "redirect" url:"/login"}`

Then in client, after getting the response, check for `action == 'redirect'` and `$location.path(url)`

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you did the authentication purely client-side.  Do an ajax call at the start on the angular end asking if we're logged in.  If not, prompt the user for information (maybe in a modal dialog) and then POST that to '/login' on the server.

For security, none of the authentication-sensitive information should be stored on the client side.  Instead, have it retrieved with ajax - and reply to the ajax with a 401 or some error if the user isn't logged in correctly.

Comment: This would be a hard implementation giving the nature of our application - I've already attempted this. I have to work with in the confines of the server architecture that's already setup, sadly. Thanks, though!